# Repeat String in braces n times

Tags: java, string, brace-expansion

I have an input String in the form "(x5(y8)2)4"

Let's say x and y are separate functions, I either want to call them 'n' times, or expand the brackets to create a new String that I can use to call the functions.

Example 1:
Input: (x5(y8)2)4
Output: x5y8y8x5y8y8x5y8y8x5y8y8

Example 2 (more complex):

Input: (((x1)3x2)4y5)2z5
Output: x1x1x1x2x1x1x1x2x1x1x1x2x1x1x1x2y5x1x1x1x2x1x1x1x2x1x1x1x2x1x1x1x2y5z5

Thanks

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. A lot fo us here don't like answering homework questions for people. Perhaps you can give it a go yourself and come back to us with specific problems you're having with your implementation. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the tree to a tree-data-structure. Each node in the tree in the has a number of children nodes. A node could either be a leaf (which is a node without children) - so for example a variable `x5` - or it could be a node (with children nodes) which represents a "mathematical" function.

The tree from your first example **could** look like this.

Root [NODE]:
*`child_of_root` * 4*

Child_of_Root [NODE]:
*`1_child_of_child_of_root` + `2_child_of_child_of_root`*

1_Child_of_Child_of_Root [LEAF]:
*`x5`*

2_Child_of_Child_of_Root [NODE]:
*`child_of_2_child_of_child_of_root * 2`*

Child_of_2_Child_of_Child_of_Root [LEAF]:
*`y8`*

To parse your input-string to the tree-structure you have to analyse how the `(` and `)` are set and if you "multiply" those by a factor and if you add other stuff - `(x5 "+" (y8) "*" 2)`. This could get quite complicated. (Maybe you could use stacks? However, I'm sure there are tutorials out there).

After you created your tree-representation of your input, it is relatively simple to calculate your output string. Create a recursive algorithm similar to this:

```
String getReult() {
    if(this == NODE) {
        return calculate(MY_NODE_CHILDREN.getResult());
    }else if(this == LEAF) {
        return VARIABLE;
    }
}
```

**This is pseudo-code!**

The calculate function should add the children string results, multiply them by a factor or do nothing, depending on a context.

If you call your recursive function at the root, the correct result should pop out.